# How to retrieve all historical public tweets with Twitter Premium Search API in Sandbox version (using next token)

Tags: python-3.x, api, twitter

I want to download all historical tweets with certain hashtags and/or keywords for a research project. I got the Premium Twitter API for that. I'm using the amazing `TwitterAPI` to take care of auth and so on.

My problem now is that I'm not an expert developer and I have some issues understanding how the `next` token works, and how to get all the tweets in a csv.

What I want to achieve is to have all the tweets in one single csv, without having to manually change the dates of the `fromDate` and `toDate` values. Right now I don't know how to get the `next` token and how to use it to concatenate requests.

So far I got here:

```
from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI
import csv

SEARCH_TERM = 'my-search-term-here'
PRODUCT = 'fullarchive'
LABEL = 'here-goes-my-dev-env'

api = TwitterAPI("consumer_key", 
             "consumer_secret", 
             "access_token_key", 
             "access_token_secret")

r = api.request('tweets/search/%s/:%s' % (PRODUCT, LABEL), 
            {'query':SEARCH_TERM, 
            'fromDate':'200603220000',
            'toDate':'201806020000'
            }
            )
csvFile = open('2006-2018.csv', 'a')
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)

for item in r:
    csvWriter.writerow([item['created_at'],item['user']['screen_name'], item['text'] if 'text' in item else item])
```

I would be really thankful for any help! 
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [TwitterAPI](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI) includes a helper class that will take care of this for you. `TwitterPager` works with many types of Twitter endpoints, not just Premium Search. Here is an example to get you started: https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI/blob/master/examples/page_tweets.py

But to answer your question, the strategy you should take is to put the request you currently have inside a `while` loop. Then,
1. Each request will return a `next` field which you can get with `r.json()['next']`. 
2. When you are done processing the current batch of tweets and ready for your next request, you would include the `next` parameter set to the value above.
3. Finally, eventually a request will not include a `next` in the the returned json. At that point break out of the `while` loop.

Something like the following.

```
next = ''
while True:
    r = api.request('tweets/search/%s/:%s' % (PRODUCT, LABEL), 
                    {'query':SEARCH_TERM, 
                     'fromDate':'200603220000',
                     'toDate':'201806020000',
                     'next':next})
    if r.status_code != 200:
        break
    for item in r:
        csvWriter.writerow([item['created_at'],item['user']['screen_name'], item['text'] if 'text' in item else item])
    json = r.json()
    if 'next' not in json:
        break
    next = json['next']
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I got the full code working (I think), or at least without errors. Problem is that I think I tried too many times, and now I get a 429 from Twitter. How can I avoid it? Just running the code fewer times in a day?

Comment: Simply obey the published [rate limits](https://developer.twitter.com/en/pricing/search-fullarchive) for your access level. If you use `TwitterPager` it has a documented `wait` parameter. Otherwise, make sure you don't exceed 30 (or 60) requests per minute.